# Enable SSL in Apache Directory Studio

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to enable SSL in Apache Directory Studio. You can see I've enabled LDAPS Server and also configured the SSLKeystore.

Now, when in do a ldapsearch from my terminal command. I get this error. Could you please suggest necessary actions.

My ldapsearch command:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -H ldaps://127.0.0.1:10636 -Z -b 'dc=example,dc=com' -D 'cn=Robert Smith,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' -w '<#password#>'
```

Terminal output:

```
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
    additional info: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache directory studio (ADS) has its own certificate store, not shared with the system's certificate stores. That's why it works in ADS but not with ldapsearch.

Depending on what operating system you use in your ldap client you will need to populate your system/user stores properly.